# Select mixed type columns including all values from an XML column?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table that has mixed column types (`int`, `varchar`, & `xml`). The `varchar` columns have XML formatted data and the `xml` column has a large node of data. I'm trying to select all the `varchar` columns with the XML included to create an XML output file using a SQL Agent job step.  The problem I'm having is the column defined as XML is padding a lot of spaces in the file and is truncating data in that column. Table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MixedTYPEXML](
    [col1] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [col2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [xmlinText1] [varchar](190) NOT NULL,
    [JOBP] [xml] NULL
) 
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[MixedTypeXML]
           ([col1]
           ,[col2]
           ,[xmlinText1]
           ,[JOBP]
           )
     VALUES
           ('Prod'
           ,'35490'
           ,'<JOBP AllowExternal="1" name="JOBP.EXTRACTS_PHP_SSIS_POST_CORE#35490">'
           ,'<PreCon><conditions id="CONDITIONS" /></PreCon>'
)
GO
```

My select statement is

```
SELECT col2, xmlinText1, JOBP from dbo.MixedTypeXML
```

The expected results are below but the actual would be several thousand records.  I'm only pulling one record with a small sample data example.

`35490  <JOBP AllowExternal="1" name="JOBP.EXTRACTS_PHP_SSIS_POST_CORE#35490">  <PreCon><conditions id="CONDITIONS" /></PreCon>`

This is just a subset of the columns I'm trying to extract.  I basically need to extract all the columns in the table including the XML defined column to send the results to an output table on the local drive without padding spaces or truncating the data. The output file will be an XML formatted file. The JOBP column sample data is just a snippet.  The actual data contains a few hundred lines of `xml` nodes.

I've looked at lots of posts on how to extract nodes and values but I'm not trying to extract specific data. I want the entire table to create an XML output file. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: (1) Please confirm that the output file shall be in XML format. (2) Please update your question and add sample data population via INSERT statements. (3) Please provide sample of the desired output based on the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the desired output, the entire output file shall be in XML format. It cannot be partially *.csv file mixed with XML elements.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    [col1] VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    [col2] INT NOT NULL,
    [xmlinText] VARCHAR(190) NOT NULL,
    [JOBP] XML NULL
);

INSERT INTO @tbl ([col1] ,[col2] ,[xmlinText] ,[JOBP])
VALUES
(
    'Prod'
    ,35490
    ,'<JOBP AllowExternal="1" name="JOBP.EXTRACTS_PHP_SSIS_POST_CORE#35490"/>'
    ,'<PreCon><conditions id="CONDITIONS" /></PreCon>'
)
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT col1, col2
    , TRY_CAST([xmlinText] AS XML) AS [xmlinText]
    , JOBP
FROM @tbl
FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE, ROOT('root');
```

> Output

```
<root>
  <row>
    <col1>Prod</col1>
    <col2>35490</col2>
    <xmlinText>
      <JOBP AllowExternal="1" name="JOBP.EXTRACTS_PHP_SSIS_POST_CORE#35490" />
    </xmlinText>
    <JOBP>
      <PreCon>
        <conditions id="CONDITIONS" />
      </PreCon>
    </JOBP>
  </row>
</root>
```

Comment: @Yuzhak This would work except I don't want to introduce new tags.  I won't be extracting the columns that contain non-XML formatted data, just `varchar` columns that contain the `XML` along with the XML defined column.  All the `XML` data columns have the necessary opening and closing tabs.

Comment: In such case, just remove the **col1** and **col2** columns from the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @Yuzhak But that still leaves the `<root>`, `<row>` tags.  Can I leave the `Path` and `ROOT` values inside the parenthesis empty?

Comment: You need them to keep the generated XML well-formed. Check it out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document

Comment: @Yuzhak  My `XML` will be well formed without those in there.  That is just going to add extra tags that I will then need to figure out how to remove.  I have several queries that will be appending `XML` to the file in the proper order and I don't want to have to remove all the `<root>` and `<row>` tags.  My main concern was having the `xml` type column padding spaces before and after the actual data when doing a `select` query with non `xml` columns that contain `xml` data.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me.  What I finally got to work was using the CONVERT string feature.

`SELECT col1, col2
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), JOBP)
FROM @tbl`